# I want to make emote chat on discord.js but there is a problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

actually this question is asked last year and the answers were very helpful but there is a problem and i couldn't figure it out and i can't comment to that answers so i decided to add questions

```
client.on('message', message => {
    const text = message.content.replace(/:[^:\s]+:|<:[^:\s]+:[0-9]+>|<a:[^:\s]+:[0-9]+>/g, '').replace(/\s+/g, '');
    if (text && message.channel.id === '772980333049020436') {
        message.delete()
        .catch(console.error);
      }
})
```

I wrote this and actually its running well for custom and animated emojis and deletes the text messages but discord's default emojis deleted too for example :smile: is deleting. How can i fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex isn't matching unicode emojis. An easy way to recognize these is by using the [`emoji-regex`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/emoji-regex) npm package.

```js
const EmojiRegex = require('emoji-regex/RGI_Emoji.js');
const text = message.content
 .replace(/:[^:\s]+:|<:[^:\s]+:[0-9]+>|<a:[^:\s]+:[0-9]+>/g, '')
 .replace(new EmojiRegex(), '');
 .replace(/\s+/g, '');
```

---

[Runkit demonstration](https://runkit.com/lioness100/5fa6cf63c7b928001a6ca7d3)